# How to find a substrings in string in two big csv file (python)

Tags: python, csv, text, matching

I have two big csv files. The main one has a field as product name and in other csv file I have some keywords. I am looking for these keywords in product name in first CSV file. At the moment my code is like this:

```
class Keyword:
    # keyword class for adding match keywords
        def __init__(self):
          self.data={}
        def add(self, keyword, count):
          if keyword in self.data.keys():
            self.data[keyword]+=count
          else:
            self.data[keyword]=count
        def get_match(self):
           temp = []
           for key, value in self.data.iteritems():
              temp.append(key)
              temp.append(value)
           return temp

for i, product_row in product_df.iterrows():
    product_title = product_row['title'].lower().replace(',','')
    k = Keyword()
    for j, keyword_row in keyword_df.iterrows():
        if keyword_row['keyword'] in product_title:
           k.add(keyword_row['keyword'], keyword_row['count'])

    match_items = k.get_match()
    if len(match_items)>0:
        temp = product_row.tolist()
        temp = [str(x).replace(',','') for x in temp]
        temp.extend(match_items)
        print>>sys.stdout, str(temp).strip('[]').replace("'",'')
    else:
        pass
```

This code is extremely slow and I have many of these csv files that should get compare with each other. Do you know more efficient way to compare these files?

Comment: fix the code indentation please.

Comment: Are you just counting the number of times each keyword *appears* in the product name field of the csv file?

Comment: Please show us a few rows from each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the entire keyword file, store the keywords in a list. After that read your products fields and check if any of the keywords are in the field, if they are then print them.

```
with open("keywords.txt", "r") as f:
    keywords = f.read().splitlines()

with open("products.txt") as f:
    for product_name in f:
        if any(keyword in product_name for keyword in keywords):
            print product_name
```

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly it becomes much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If your keywords are really single words, rather than multiword expressions, my first suggestion is to convert the product title into a set for faster lookups:

```
product_title = set(product_row['title'].lower().replace(',','').split())
```

Comment: The problem is that keywords can be bigram, trigram and so on. I would like to know for which products these keywords are repeated.

Comment: Do you care about the order of words in bi-, tri, etc. -grams? If not, you can pre-convert keywords to sets, too, and calculate set intersection with the title word set: `if keyword_row['keyword'] & product_title:`

Comment: Yes, order of them is important.

Comment: Last suggestion: keep two copies of both keywords and titles: one as a string and one as a set of strings. In the loop, first calculate set intersection. If the intersection is empty, there is no match. If the intersection is not empty, check for the match with `in`. If intersections are rare, this may save you some time.